# What is extrn analogue in AT&T assembler?

Tags: c, assembly, extern, att

In FASM - extrn, in NASM - extern, but what is in AT&T ?
I need it in my C program.

Comment: You don't need it. [*as treats all undefined symbols as external*](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Extern.html#Extern).

Comment: If you're defining a variable in asm and needing it in your C program, you want `.globl` in GAS and `extern int foo` in C, like the 2nd duplicate shows.  The first duplicate answers the title question like RKHB did.